# remove() javascript function not working properly

Tags: javascript, webpack, dom

I am making a resturant page and I have home, contact and menu tabs. When I initially click on a tab the page shows up, however when I click on the same tab or another tab,instead of deleting the first page and placing in the new one, another page shows up right underneath the first

dist/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Restaurant</title>
   
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content">

        
    </div>
   <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

src/tab.js

```
import home from './home.js';
import menu from './menu.js';
import contact from './contact.js';

export default function tabs() {

  
  const element = document.getElementById('content');
  const homebutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  const hometext = document.createTextNode("Home");

  homebutton.appendChild(hometext);

  const contactbutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  const contacttext = document.createTextNode("Contact");


  contactbutton.appendChild(contacttext);

  const menubutton = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  const menutext = document.createTextNode("Menu");

  menubutton.appendChild(menutext);


  homebutton.addEventListener('click', button => {

    if(element.contains(menu()))
    {
      menu().remove();
    }
       
    if(element.contains(contact()))
    {
      contact().remove();
    }
       
       element.appendChild(home());

  });
  
  menubutton.addEventListener('click', button => {
    if(element.contains(contact()))
    {
      contact().remove();
    }
    if(element.contains(home()))
    {
      home().remove();
    }

    element.appendChild(menu());

});

contactbutton.addEventListener('click', button => {
 
  if(element.contains(menu()))
  {
    menu().remove();
  }
  if(element.contains(home()))
    {
      home().remove();
    }


  element.appendChild(contact());

});
  
  
  element.appendChild(homebutton);
  element.appendChild(contactbutton);
  element.appendChild(menubutton);


  return element;


}
```

src/menu.js

```
import Birriatacopic from './BiriaTacos.jpg';
import Quesadillapic from './Qesadilla.png';
import Burritopic from './burrito.png';


export default function menu() {
    const element = document.createElement('div');
    const burrito = document.createElement("p");
    const quesadilla = document.createElement("p");
    const birriataco = document.createElement("p");

    burrito.innerHTML = "Burrito";

    const burritoIcon = new Image();
       burritoIcon.src = Burritopic;
     

    quesadilla.innerHTML = "Quesadilla";

    const quesadillaIcon = new Image();
       quesadillaIcon.src = Quesadillapic;
     
     
    birriataco.innerHTML = "Birria Tacos";

    const birriaTacoIcon = new Image();
       birriaTacoIcon.src = Birriatacopic;
     
    element.appendChild(burrito);

    element.appendChild(burritoIcon);

    element.appendChild(quesadilla); 

    element.appendChild(quesadillaIcon);

    element.appendChild(birriataco); 

    element.appendChild(birriaTacoIcon); 


    return element;

}
```

src/index.js

```
import _ from 'lodash';

import tabs from './tab.js';
  
 
 
 document.body.appendChild(tabs())
```

Comment: Highly repetitive code. Stay DRY and delegate

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add an id to element in src/menu.js

```
element.id = "MENU";
```

In src/tab.js

```
if(element.contains(document.getElementById("MENU")))
    {
      document.getElementById("MENU").remove();
    }
```